# Calling Plain JS function from view

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have trouble getting my head around how to call Javascript functions in a view. What I want to achieve is a HTML-Table where some fields are updated regularly based on some parameters.

So I need a function with parameters which gets the respective HTML Element and sets an interval in which the elements.innerHTML is set. So far, so good. I have this function

```
export default function calcActual(amount, gain, time, index) {
var td;
td = document.getElementById('ressource_' + index);
  setInterval(function() {
    td.innerHTML = "actual: " + Math.round(amount + (gain / 3600) * time);
  }, Math.round(gain / 3600));}
```

in `'priv/js/views/user_assets/rou.js'`

In my 'app.js' I have the following:

```
import { calcActual } from './views/user_assets/rou';
```

As far as I understood, all the code from app.js is stuffed in a module, so I just don't have any possibility to call the function directly. My next thought was to wrap the function again in app.js and call it from there.

```
export var Calc = {
  calcActual: function(amount, gain, time, index) {
    calcActualRes(amount, gain, time, index)
  }
}
```

but I always get the error that `Calc` is not defined, when trying to call the function with:

```
 <td id="ressource_<%= index %>">
   actual:<script>Calc.calcActual(
                <%= amount %>,
                <%= gain %>,
                <%= NaiveDateTime.diff(NaiveDateTime.utc_now, ressource.updated_at) %>,
                <%= index %>)
    </script>
  </td>
```

Can anyone explain, why this fails and how to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to actually import the module using `require` before using it:

```
<script>
var calcActual = require('views/user_assets/rou');
// do your stuff with calcActual.
</script>
```

Just make sure that `app.js` is loaded before you call `require` function, otherwise it will complain `require` is not defined.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I already was at that point, but as you mentioned require was not defined and I was not sure, why that happened either. app.js will now be loaded before and everything works fine.